# CoffeeScript to attach objects to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to implement application dialogs (modals) using CoffeeScript.

The intent is you do some action which creates a CoffeeScript dialog object and attaches it to an array on the page so they can be referenced later (in case there are multiple).

When some event such as clicking an overlay occurs, I want to hide the overlay but also any existing dialogs by destroying them.

I am using jQuery for convenience as well.

My desire is to learn how to use JavaScript/CoffeeScript objects to interact with the DOM instead of having a bunch of global events firing all over the place in one massive JS file.

At the moment, when I call `dialog.destroy()` below, the console (using Chrome dev tools) states:

`Uncaught TypeError: dialog.destroy is not a function`

HTML page

```
<a href="#" id="create-dialog-link">Link</a>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

CoffeeScript global file

```
$("#create-dialog-link").on "click", ->
  new Dialog("<div class='dialog'>content</div>")

$("#overlay").on "click", ->
  this.hide() # Hide overlay
  dialog.destroy() for dialog in window.dialogs
```

CoffeeScript Dialog class

```
class @Dialog
  constructor: (element) ->
    window.dialogs ||= [] # Initialize "global" array of dialogs
    @element = $(element) # Turn into jQuery object
    $("#overlay").show()
    @append_to_body()

  append_to_body: ->
    $("body").append(@element) # Actually add HTML to DOM
    window.dialogs.push(@element) # Store array of dialogs

  destroy: ->
    @element.remove() # Completely remove from DOM
```

Comment: What probably helps in finding your own answer is realising that you are not doing it 'with coffeescript', but with jQuery. Coffeescript is just a syntax that parses to another one (Javascript).

Comment: @muistooshort: I updated the Dialog class constructor with that code (`window.dialogs ||= []`)

Comment: @muistooshort: Why do I need to reference `window.dialog` (singular)?  The intent is to create an array of JS objects and then call the `destroy()` method on each of them in the event handler for `#overlay`.  I'm just not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the `for` loop in the click handler, hence my confusion about `dialog` vs `dialogs`. Have you looked at `window.dialogs` in the click handler to see what it actually contains rather than what you expect it to contain? A class property (`@dialogs: [ ]`) in your `Dialog` class would be better than `window.dialogs`, then you could add a class method to `Dialog` and say `Dialog.destroy_all()` in the overlay's click handler instead of messing around with globals.

Comment: @muistooshort: that's a good idea; I was curious about adding a class-level variable vs a window global.  I actually found my problem, and it was close to what you were talking about. When I did `window.dialogs.push(@element)`, it should actually be `window.dialogs.push(this)`...I was pushing the jQuery object for the DIV instead of the Dialog object.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem with some help from @muistooshort!

```
# this line...
window.dialogs.push(@element)

# should be this...
window.dialogs.push(this)
```

I was pushing the jQuery `div` object that represented the DOM element instead of the `Dialog` object itself.  `Dialog#destroy()` exists, but `$("div").#destroy()` does not...

Comment: And the other thing I was talking about would look something like this https://gist.github.com/mu-is-too-short/e9094620ea1632346b01 (untested code)

Comment: @muistooshort: if you throw that in as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. You're code is cleaner than what I was going with, as I was clogging up global window spaces.

Comment: That wasn't really an answer though, just a suggestion of an alternate approach. The `push(@element)` vs `push(this)` problem would be the same in either case. I'm happy with just the comment, no worries.